# create multiple buttons in a view via loop

Tags: javascript, react-native, touchableopacity

I want to create multiple custom buttons for my react-native app. 
I'm using an array with all the informations in it and I want to iterate over all buttons in the array and create all buttons in one single view.
I tried something like this:

```
<View>
  for( let i=0; i<numberButtons; i++) {
          <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.mapView, this.props.mapViewStyle]} >
            <Image
              style={[styles.image, this.props.imageStyle]}
              source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
}
</View>
```

That doesn't seem to work. I get errors from the react-native framework so I guess you can't do js in a view?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
renderButtons = () => {
  const buttons = [];
  for( let i = 0; i < numberButtons; i++) {
     buttons.push(
      <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.mapView, this.props.mapViewStyle]}>
        <Image
          style={[styles.image, this.props.imageStyle]}
          source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_og.png'}}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
  return buttons;
}



render() {
  return (
    <View>
      {this.renderButtons()}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: ok cool, thank you:) Can you explain why I can't iterate and do stuff the "normal" way?

Comment: Sure, anytime you want to use javascript you will have to put it into brackets { }, I believe whatever you return in the render will be read as JSX.

Comment: Oh wait. It seems like it is not working. Don't I need to `return()` the created touchableOpacity ?

Comment: something like this? [example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/69f71a8f06eb85c1ad5b3f898788d8d3)Although it's not working like that.